# Java change value of variable after casting to Object

Tags: java

I'm trying to change a variable after casting it to an object.
Is this possible in Java or are there other options to do something similar?

```
Double a = 1.;
Object o = a;
Double b = (Double)o;
b = 2.;
System.out.println(a); // print 2
```

Comment: Nope, this is not possible.

Comment: All you've done is assigned the reference `b` to the `double` `2`. This smells like an XY problem to me - what is your _actual_ issue?

Comment: same will happen without casting and the intermediate Object. Actually same for primitives `int i = 1; int j = i; j = 2;` will not change `i` to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two references pointing to the same object you cannot change the of both references assigning one if them to a new object.

```
Double a = 1.,
Double b = a;
Double b = 2.; // here b now points to new object. a is not changed. Now you have two separate variables pointing to separate objects.
```

If you really need that then you need to use wrapper class which has setter/better to manipulate internal state

```
DoubleWrapper a = new DoubleWrapper(2); // not a standard JDK class. You will need to write it yourself
DoubleWrapper b = a;
b.set(1);
System.out.println(b.get()); // prints 1
System.out.println(a.get()); // also prints 1
```

Comment: Sure. But that is irrelevant. There isn't any call to any method here. Only assignments.